# XAML Button Content not showing when Template is applied

Tags: wpf, xaml, templates, button, styles

I'm trying this custom template code for each control and the second button in my grid doesn't how its content. Here is my code snippet.

```
'<Grid>  
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
     <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
     <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>         
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>      
  <Grid.Resources>
     <!-- First Template -->
     <ControlTemplate x:Key="TBtnOpen" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Border x:Name="Border" CornerRadius="4">
           <Border.Background><!-- Default Diagonal Gradient-->
              <LinearGradientBrush>
                 <GradientStop Color="DarkGreen" Offset="0"/>
                 <GradientStop Color="LightGreen" Offset="0.5"/>
                 <GradientStop Color="DarkBlue" Offset="1"/>        
              </LinearGradientBrush>
           </Border.Background>
           <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
        </Border>
     </ControlTemplate>
     <!-- Second Template -->
     <ControlTemplate x:Key="TBtnCloseHor" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Border x:Name="Border" CornerRadius="8">
           <Border.Background>
              <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0.5" EndPoint="1,0.5"> <!-- Horizontal Gradient-->
                 <GradientStop Color="Violet" Offset="0"></GradientStop>
                 <GradientStop Color="LightBlue" Offset="0.2"></GradientStop>
                 <GradientStop Color="DarkGreen" Offset="0.4"></GradientStop>
                 <GradientStop Color="Red" Offset="0.6"></GradientStop>
                 <GradientStop Color="Yellow" Offset="0.8"></GradientStop>
                 <GradientStop Color="DarkOrange" Offset="1"></GradientStop>
              </LinearGradientBrush>
           </Border.Background>
        </Border>
     </ControlTemplate>
     <!-- Controls Styles -->
     <Style x:Key="BtnStyles" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="40"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="100"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="25"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="FontStyle" Value="Italic"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Arial"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"></Setter>
     </Style>
  </Grid.Resources>  
  <Button  Grid.Column="0" x:Name="btnFirst"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
           Style="{StaticResource BtnStyles}"
           Template="{StaticResource TBtnOpen}">Open!
    <Button.Margin>10</Button.Margin>        
    <Button.Foreground>Black</Button.Foreground>        
  </Button>  
  <Button Grid.Column="1" x:Name="btnSecond" HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
          Style="{StaticResource BtnStyles}" Template="{StaticResource TBtnCloseHor}">Close!<!-- This is the missing Content-->
     <Button.Margin>10</Button.Margin>  
     <Button.Foreground>White</Button.Foreground>         
  </Button>  </Grid>'
```

If a apply the same Template (TBtnOpen) to both button controls it works fine yet applying different templates each hide second button Content. 
Any advice would be much appreciated. 
Thanks 
Tony.

PS: Sample image at link bellow. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i1vtk.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using custom template, it is necessary to specify the `<ContentPresenter/>` otherwise WPF will not understand where the content should goes to. Thus, try to add it to your custom template and your content will be displayed even if you don't specify `VerticalAlignment`and `HorizontalAlignment`

```
            <ControlTemplate x:Key="TBtnCloseHor" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Border x:Name="Border" CornerRadius="8">
            <ContentPresenter/>
                <Border.Background>
                    <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0.5" EndPoint="1,0.5">
                        <!-- Horizontal Gradient-->
                        <GradientStop Color="Violet" Offset="0"></GradientStop>
                        <GradientStop Color="LightBlue" Offset="0.2"></GradientStop>
                        <GradientStop Color="DarkGreen" Offset="0.4"></GradientStop>
                        <GradientStop Color="Red" Offset="0.6"></GradientStop>
                        <GradientStop Color="Yellow" Offset="0.8"></GradientStop>
                        <GradientStop Color="DarkOrange" Offset="1"></GradientStop>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Border.Background>
            </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what is causing it, but I know how to fix it. You should bind the content of a Border.

Write this inside your Borders:

```
<ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Content="{Binding Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```